# Triangulation of $\mathbb{R}P^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

How to give a tiangulation of  $\mathbb{R}P^n$, for general $n>=2$? I know how to do this when $n=2$, but I don't know the general case. Also, I know the CW-structure of  $\mathbb{R}P^n$, does this structure relevant to my problem?

Comment: Googling for "triangulation of real projective spaces" gives as first result http://mathoverflow.net/questions/50382/how-to-triangulate-real-projective-spaces-as-simplicial-complexes-in-mathematic